# how to open library i created by myself in my code

Tags: c++, header, static-libraries

[image: proof that "streamlib/framework.h" doesnt work][image: the directory in which the vs code is]I've created a library called streamlib.lib
the library was created by mashing or however you'd call it an h file called framework.h
i used name space in the following manner:
namespace msl
{
}
in the .h file and in the .cpp file aswell.
im trying to add the library and use a function in the framework.h file, but first i had to include the library itself.
how can i do that?
things ive tried:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "streamlib.lib")

#include <streamlib/framework.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "streamlib.lib")

#include <streamlib/framework.h>

#include "framework.h"

#include "streamlib.lib"
```

but i have yet to find a way.
has anybody got an idea?
compiler won't compile saying he cannot include the file.
specification: framework.h is in streamlib.lib which is in the same folder as the cpp file im trying to include the library to.

Comment: What's giving you grief, the linking of the library or compiler problems with the header?

Comment: The compiler won't compile the code, saying he doesn't recognize the header

Comment: Thanks. Please add to your question where framework.h is. If it is inside the projects folders, `#include "framework.h"` may be correct, but if its not in the same folder as the compiled code you may need something more like `#include "streamlib/framework.h"`. If it's not in the project, you need `#include <streamlib/framework.h>` and add the location to Project->Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories.

Comment: It is in the same folder as the compiled code but in the library streamlib.lib. i had tried #include "streamlib/framework.h" but it hasn't worked. any otheer suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you need  `#include "../streamlib/framework.h"`

Comment: ***It is in the same folder as the compiled code but in the library streamlib.lib*** I find this description somewhat contradictory or at least confusing. Is the library in a subfolder of the applications code? Is the header in the exact same folder as the application's headers?

Comment: @drescherjm beg your pardon, the header file is in the library which is in the subfolder where the c file is. how should i go on from here?

Comment: Then it should be `#include "streamlib/framework.h"` if the streamlib folder is in the same folder as your source files for your application.

Comment: Update the question with the extra information. Be explicit about the project structure. Consider drawing ascii art pictures of the folder layout. Side note: `#include "streamlib.lib"` is incorrect no matter how the rest of the answer pans out.

Comment: @drescherjm doesn't work aswell. have updated the inforamation so you could perhaps get a better grasp of the question as user4581301 suggested

Comment: I think you need to show a picture of your directory structure. And yes `#include "streamlib.lib"` is wrong in any context.

Comment: @drescherjm i've added a picture of my directory.

Comment: I don't see the `streamlib` folder in the directory listing. Is it there?

Comment: @drescherjm streamlib is the static library i created, not a folder, or perhaps i completely misunderstood what a library is

Comment: ***streamlib is the static library i created*** I know that part. I thought before you said there was a folder named exactly `streamlib` and that was in this folder that you are showing. It needs to be for `#include "streamlib/framework.h"` to work without adding an entry in your `Additional Include Directories` setting for your project.

Comment: @drescherjm "streamlib/framework.h" doesnt work as i showed in my image. i puposefully took a picture with my vs in case there is an error in that.

Comment: Where is that file `framework.h`  located in respect to the folder containing `streamtest.cpp`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203557/discussion-between-ron-zamir-and-drescherjm).